# Sci-fi short story about highway patrol officers that can execute traffic offenders

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The story includes at least two young drivers.  There is a horrific accident that kills a little girl.  One of the young men was a repeat offender who does not show remorse.  the other offender had modified the "transponder" on the vehicle to hide the vehicle location.

One offender was executed the other was not because he had the potential to be able to learn and grow in society.

I can't remember the name of the story or the author.  It is not "Code 3."

Comment: The suspense is killing me.  Which one was executed??!??!?

Comment: @James Mayfield III - In roughly which year or decade did you read this, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, did you read it in an anthology, a magazine, or online?

Comment: Is the executioner human or robot?

Comment: There was a sequel to "Code Three" (the story), called "Once a Cop"

Comment: I wonder if this is the same as [Short story set in near future: huge freeways and swift justice for bad driving](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/156674/short-story-set-in-near-future-huge-freeways-and-swift-justice-for-bad-driving). That was closed as a duplicate of *Code Three* but I suspect this is wrong since no-one is executed in *Code Three*.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the correct answer was given in a [comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/156674/short-story-set-in-near-future-huge-freeways-and-swift-justice-for-bad-driving#comment462929_156674) under the [post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/156674/short-story-set-in-near-future-huge-freeways-and-swift-justice-for-bad-driving) mentioned by John Rennie. Agree that one likely was mis-ID'd.

It wasn't the transponder that was modified, it was the height control circuitry. This allowed the flying car to go low enough to strike the little girl.

The driver was executed, the 2nd guy was sentenced to a term of service on a lunar colony because he was smart enough to figure out how to modify the car.

"[10:01 AM](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?45493)" by Alexander Malec.

Read it in the [March 1966 Analog](https://drive.google.com/open?id=10gUfYPHBEUQrplRy_aSYi2cNuCsf6KKY) from the Luminist Archive. (link is to pdf via a Google Drive)